# While uploading pdf showing error in ajax call error 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, http-status-code-403

facing some problem While uploading pdf showing error in ajax call error 403 forbidden a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page here is my ajax call >> upload pdf ajax call please resolve this

```
 `function submitIndividualSharedFileInviteCandidate() {
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $('#individual')[0].files
            data.append('file',files[0]);
            if (!validateIndividualResumeUpload()) {
                return false;
            }else{     
                if(dummyData == "DummyData"){
                    currentactivity_dummyData = "btn_shareEmployee_uploadIndResume";
                    deleteDummyData();
                    removeDummyData="removeDummyData";
                    }
              }     


            // var data = new FormData(formdata);
            var csrf = $("input[name='_csrf']").attr("value")

            $.ajax({
                headers : {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : csrf
                },
                type : 'multipart/form-data',
                processData : false, // Important!
                contentType: false,
                cache : false, //this is my servlet
                data : data,
                type : "POST",
                url : "./parseResume",

                success : function(result) {
                    if (result.status == "Done") {
                        current_employee_id = result.data.employeeId;
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#candidatesBlock1').empty();

                        
                    }
                    $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(2)").trigger('click')
            $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(1)").css('pointer-events',    'none');
                    $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('height', '698px');
                    $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('overflow', 'auto');
                    
                    getSupplierEmail()
                    
                    var obj = result.data;
                    unparsed_resumes_list = obj;
                    current_employee_id = obj.employeeId;
                    $('#userId_unparesedResume').val(obj.employeeId);
                    unparsedBulkSharedResumePreview(obj);
                    $('#btn_save_unparsedSharedBulkResumes').html('Save');

                    
                    if (result.status == "error") {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        
                    }
                },
                error : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
            }`
```

while uploading pdf showing this error 403 Forbidden a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page

Comment: 403 is Forbidden Error. It should be verify in Server side

Comment: ok how i can verify